# delet duplicates data from a queryset in django (code not working)

Tags: python, django

I'm working on a Django project and need some help .

I am trying to delete duplicated data from my table, i tried this :

```
for sign in Signal.objects.values_list('signal_name', flat=True).distinct():
    Signal.objects.filter(pk__in=Signal.objects.filter(signal_name=sign).values_list('id', flat=True)[1:]).delete()
```

But it deletes all the data from the table, anyone knows what's the problem with my code?

Comment: The distinct values are the ones you want to keep, so instead query for the duplicates and do a delete on that query

Comment: sorry, but i don't get it , can you past it as code?

Comment: I've linked to a duplicate.

Comment: i still don't get it , can you writed as a code? thanks!